# definstances syntax of inherited classes CLIPS

Tags: clips

I have class B that inherits class A and I'm trying to create object of class b, here is what I have done

```
 (defclass a(is-a OBJECT)(role abstract)(slot column1))
    (defclass  b(is-a a) (role concrete)(slot column2))
    (definstances myobjects
    (object1 of myobjects (column1 A)(column2 B))
    (object1 of myobjects (column1 A)(column2 C))
    )
```

I'm getting error in defineinstances syntax
How can I make instance of class B
secondary question 
 is there a way to put in a slot two variables in defineinstances syntax and search it later with either value. i'm not talking about using symbols in defclass part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CLIPS> 
(defclass a
  (is-a USER)
  (role abstract)
  (slot column1))
CLIPS>    
(defclass b
  (is-a a) 
  (role concrete)
  (multislot column2))
CLIPS> 
(definstances myobjects
  (object1 of b (column1 A) (column2 B C)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (instances)
[initial-object] of INITIAL-OBJECT
[object1] of b
For a total of 2 instances.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: If you're using wxCLIPS from 1996, the syntax has to match what was available in CLIPS twenty years ago. In this case you have to explicitly specify that slot accessors should be created. For example: (slot column1 (create-accessor read-write)).